# How to properly sync multiple reader/single writer threads using just atomic operations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++17, lock-free

I'm developing a data processing system in which the incoming portions of information constantly flow in, get buffered and then, once in a while, processed. So I'm using a double-buffer approach, in which the incoming info is stored in one buffer while the other one gets processed. Something like this:

```
struct data_bundle_1 { /* ... */ };
struct data_bundle_2 { /* ... */ };
// ...
struct data_bundle_n { /* ... */ };

struct data_buffer {
    data_bundle_1 data_1;
    data_bundle_2 data_2;
    // ...
    data_bundle_n data_n;

    std::atomic_int buffer_writer_count;
};

data_buffer double_buf[2];
std::atomic<data_buffer*> current_buf;
int current_buf_index = 0;
```

The data buffer is filled by multiple writer threads, so each data bundle in the `data_buffer` structure will have an internal lock (most probably an `atomic_flag`-based spinlock) to protect it from possible data races.

The thing I'm not so sure about is how to avoid data races when switching the buffers. When it comes to working with `current_buf`, the data writers become readers and the buffer switcher is a writer.

This is the solution that comes to mind, but I'm not sure whether my approach is correct.

```
// threads #1, 2, ..., m
void data_writer_routine (/* data batch */) {
    data_buffer* cur_buf = current_buf.load(std::memory_order_acquire); // (1)
    cur_buf->buffer_writer_count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release); // (2)

    {
        // in case buffer switching happened between (1) and (2)
        data_buffer* new_cur_buf = curent_buf.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (cur_buf != new_cur_buf) {
            cur_buf->buffer_writer_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
            (cur_buf = new_cur_buf)->buffer_writer_count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }

    /* add the data batch to the buffer */

    cur_buf->buffer_writer_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release); // (3)
}

// thread #m+1
void buffer_switching_routine () {
    data_buffer old_buf = current_buf.exchange(
        &(double_buf[(current_buf_index=1-current_buf_index)]),
        std::memory_order_release); // (4)

    // waiting till all the data writers are done with the old buffer
    while (old_buf->buffer_writer_count.load(std::memory_order_acquire)); // (5)

    /* process the data from old_buf */
}
```

Basically, I would like understand three things:

1. After the statement (4) is executed by the thread #m+1 (that's the sole thread that could switch the buffers), is there any guarantee that the subsequent execution of the statement (1) by the threads #1-m would return value set in (4)?
2. Am I using the memory order constants properly, i.e. is it okay to have multiple subsequent acquire operations on the same atomic within the same thread, is it okay to have multiple acquire operations per single release operation (and multiple release operations per single acquire operation) across multiple threads?
3. If this whole construction is faulty (i.e. there's no guarantee I'm asking about in clause 1 and after (4) and (5) are finished by the thread #m+1, one of the threads #1-m might execute (1) and receive the "old" value, thus opening the road to a data race), what would be the right way of syncing those threads using just the atomic operations? I know about `std::shared_mutex` but would really like to avoid performance penalties incurred by using the kernel-level synchronization.

Comment: If you have to ask, you have no business trying to write lock-free code. You will get it wrong. Use a mutex and if you find that your code is too slow (you won't) tackle the problem then.

Comment: @RichardHodges, how would one learn to write lock-free code then? Seriously, this is a Q&A site, and you reprimand me for asking a question. Maybe my code is silly, but what you suggest is plain counterproductive.

Comment: Lock free code is extremely hard. Experts (and I mean library maintainers who's job it is) often make mistakes. What I am suggesting is your most productive course of action. Use a mutex. They're not slow, and they always work.

Comment: @RichardHodges, I'm not trying to do anything complex, e.g. writing lock-free containers or anything. Basically I've been looking for any mutex-free implementation of a multiple-reader/single-writer lock, and I found none. Instead, I found some benchmarks showing that, for example, in Windows mutexes are implemented so horrendously bad that locking a mutex 10k times per second is a very bad idea (don't have the actual numbers at hand, but those were nasty, and the suggestion was to try using atomics for locking, hence my question)

Comment: benchmark first, then make a decision. Honestly, you'll be glad you did.

Comment: You can roll your own readers/writers lock (or pretty much anything else) with `std::atomic`.  It's powerful enough to express pretty much everything you can do with asm.  Of course, a platform-specific implementation can do things that are *very* important for performance, like using the `pause` instruction in spin-loops on x86, and falling back to OS-specific system calls after spinning a few times.  But for just correctness, yes you can roll your own of anything.

Comment: "Basically I've been looking for any mutex-free implementation of a multiple-reader/single-writer lock, and I found none" Guess why ? Because it is not easy at all. You can have a look at https://github.com/HadrienG2/spmc-buffer tho. And if you really want to go deep, write wait free code instead of lock free code (it is even harder XD)